# Date Formatted as an Int but need to be reformated as date

Tags: r

i have a column that contains dates in the following format:

`Date
 19880101
 19880102
 19880103
 20170501
 20180516`

R is treating is as an Int of course. is there a way i can reformat it to be DD-MM-YYYY
i have tried `as.Date(x,"%m/%d/%Y")` but that does not not work

Comment: Please study the documentation regarding format strings. `as.Date(as.character(c(19880101, 19880102)), format = "%Y%m%d")`

Comment: `as.Date(as.character(d), "%Y%m%d")`

Comment: @dash2 thank you so much mate, that worked perfectly! if you put it as an answer i will mark it

Comment: @Roland did you down vote me? if so why? i am clearly new to R and i have stated my question correctly and showed effort

Comment: I downvoted you. Your question isn't stated correctly - you don't use `dput` to make your example reproducible. And it's not a very useful question - it's too specific and could be answered by a careful look at `?as.Date`. Nothing personal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After being enlightened by more experienced members of the community i am able to pass on their knowledge in form of the following answer:

`x <- as.Date(as.character(x), "%Y%m%d")`

thanks for your comments @Roland and @dash2 you are truly inspiring!